# How to write a Saxon ExtensionFunctionDefinition which can handle either SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING or SequenceType.EMPTY_SEQUENCE

Tags: java, saxon

I have written a Saxon HE extension function as below

```
package com.commander4j.Transformation;

import com.commander4j.util.Utility;

import net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionCall;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition;
import net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence;
import net.sf.saxon.om.StructuredQName;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;
import net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType;
import net.sf.saxon.value.StringValue;

public class XSLT_Ext_trim extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition
{

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes()
    {
        return new SequenceType[]{SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING};
    }
    
    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName()
    {
        return new StructuredQName("c4j_XSLT_Ext_trim", "http://com.commander4j.Transformation.XSLT_Ext_trim", "trim");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] arg0)
    {
         return SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression()
    {
           return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
                @Override
                public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                    
                    String value;
                    try
                    {
                        value =  arguments[0].head().getStringValue();
                    } catch (ClassCastException ex)
                    {
                       value = "";  
                    }
                    
                    String result = Utility.replaceNullStringwithBlank(value);

                    return StringValue.makeStringValue(result);
                }
            };
    }

}
```

It works unless the parameter passed to it from my XSQL select is an Empty Sequence.

Can I amend the code below so that it will accept either and if it encounters an empty sequence treat it as a blank string?

I have determined that using the string(....) cast on my XSLT select works but I'm trying to understand the SAXON Java code a little more and was wondering if a change to that code would mean that all my calls to this extension function would be fixed with a single change rather than hunting down all the calls to it.

Comment: What happens if it does not work, which error or result do you get, do you get it in the Java code or on the XSLT side? If you get an exception in the Java code on e.g. `arguments[0].head()` then catch that, if `arguments[0].head()` returns null then check for that before calling getStringValue().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly declare the argument type, and if necessary the result type, as `SequenceType.OPTIONAL_STRING`.

Secondly, write your code so that it deals with the case where `arguments[0].head()` returns null.

Comment: So I need to check if arguments[0].head() is null - which means that the value is simply not available to read at that point in time (and maybe should try again) and this is distinct from arguments[0].head().getStringValue(); being null which means that the value returned from the XML being parsed is missing. Have I understood correctly ?

Comment: arguments[0].head() will be null if the value of the argument is an empty sequence. If arguments[0].head() is non-null, then the sequence contains at least one item. Calling getStringValue() on an item will never return null, though it may throw an exception if the item is one of the few kinds of item that don't have a string value, for example, a map.

Comment: However, your code only has to deal with arguments that match the declared argument type. If the declared type is SequenceType.OPTIONAL_STRING, then you are guaranteed that either arg[0].head() will be null (an empty sequence) or it will be an instance of xs:string, represented in Java by a `net.sf.saxon.value.StringValue`. If the XPath/XSLT caller supplies something invalid, like an integer or a map, then Saxon will detect the error and won't call your function.